# How to set entry point of a process created from CreateProcess

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, createprocess, entry-point

I am using CreateProcess to invoke     `cl`     to compile and link another C++ program (`TestProg.cxx`) into a DLL. I invoke `cl` with the following compilation options:

```
/Od /nologo /Fo /RTC /w /Zc /EHsc /I\INCLUDE /I\LIB /I\PATH TestProg.cxx /DLL
```

the call:

```
if ( CreateProcess(full path to cl.exe, compilation options, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,       NULL,NULL,&si,&pi) ) 
{
 //....
}
```

Running the application from VS tools prompt, I got the following linkage error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I searched the answer for the last 1/2 day at the web, but didn't find it. Using windows API is new to me.

Thanks

Comment: Do `TestProg.css` have a [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run cl from command line?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I added a default DllMain() to my `TestProg.cxx` 

`extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}`

and also added `/Entry:DllMain` to the link options.

But now I got the following linkage errors: 

`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMain
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
main.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals`

Could you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error in using `CreateProcess()` to run the compiler, it's an error from the compiler telling you that your `TestProg.cxx` has no `main()` function.  (Or `DllMain()`, since you seem to be building a DLL.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the DllMain() below to my `TestProg.cxx`:

`extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}`

and also added `/Entry:DllMain` to the link options.

Now I get the following errors: 

`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMain
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
main.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals`

Could you please explain how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I don't actually do Windows programming, so I don't know what link options or special declarations you may be missing.  You should ask this as a new question, and include the actual code that you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linker error, so linker was unable to build you a binary. The entry point can be provided via `/ENTRY` command line parameter, see MSDN for details:

[/ENTRY (Entry-Point Symbol)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You will have something like: `cl.exe /ENTRY:DllMain ...` where DllMain will be your entry point function in source code.